# Getting a null object exception when using an interface

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, nullpointerexception

I have created a shopping cart via recyclerview. Each viewholder also has a + and - button to add or remove quantity. This functionality is done in the adapter and I have to notify the parent fragment of the updated total amount. This last bit is done via an interface. The problem is, I am getting the following error:

```
Process: com.ecomm.market, PID: 6630
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.ecomm.market.SelectionAdapter$OnUpdateCartListener.onUpdateCart(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.ecomm.market.SelectionAdapter$ViewHolder$1.onClick(SelectionAdapter.java:103)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

The selected item and corresponding quantity are stored in a hashmap that I convert to an array to populate the recycler view cart. This is what the relevant part of my main fragment **MenuFragment** looks like:

```
                // Using the adapter interface to add items to cart and adding up total amount
                menuItemAdapter.setOnAddToCartListener(new MenuItemAdapter.OnAddToCartListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAddToCart(final HashMap selectionItemsHashMap) {

                        setupSelectionRecycler(menuView);
                        totalAmount = mapToArray(selectionItemsHashMap);

                            selectionAdapter = new SelectionAdapter(selectionItemArrayList, selectionItemsHashMap, totalAmount);

                        selectionRecycler.setAdapter(selectionAdapter);
                        cartItemsHashmap = selectionItemsHashMap;

                        selectionAdapter.setUpdateCartListener(new SelectionAdapter.OnUpdateCartListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onUpdateCart(int updatedTotalAmount) {

                                String stringTotalAmount = Integer.toString(updatedTotalAmount);
                                Log.d(TAG, "received total:" +stringTotalAmount);
                                tvTotalAmount.setText("$"+ stringTotalAmount);
                                totalAmount = updatedTotalAmount;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
```

And here is an excerpt from my adapter **SelectionAdapter**:

```
public class SelectionAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SelectionAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = SelectionAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private ArrayList<SelectionItem> selectionItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    public HashMap<String, Integer> selectionItemsHashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    public int totalAmount;

    private OnUpdateCartListener updateCartListener;

    public interface OnUpdateCartListener {
        void onUpdateCart(int totalAmount);
    }

    public void setUpdateCartListener(OnUpdateCartListener updateCartListener) {
        this.updateCartListener = updateCartListener;
    }

    public SelectionAdapter(ArrayList<SelectionItem> selectionItemArrayList, HashMap<String, Integer> selectionItemsHashMap, int currentTotalAmount) {
        this.selectionItemArrayList = selectionItemArrayList;
        this.selectionItemsHashMap = selectionItemsHashMap;
        this.totalAmount = currentTotalAmount;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.selection_card, viewGroup, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        viewHolder.tvSelectItem.setText(selectionItemArrayList.get(position).getSelectionName());
        String quantity = Integer.toString(selectionItemArrayList.get(position).getSelectionQuantity());
        viewHolder.tvDishQuantity.setText(quantity);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return selectionItemArrayList.size();
    }


    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvSelectItem, tvDishQuantity;
        ImageView addQuantity, subtractQuantity, deleteItem;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            tvSelectItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dish_selection);
            tvDishQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dish_quantity);

            addQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_add);
            subtractQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button_subtract);
            deleteItem = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_item);

            addQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    // Find the name of the menu item
                    int position = getAdapterPosition();
                    String itemName = selectionItemArrayList.get(position).getSelectionName();

                    // Increase quantity
                    int currentQuantity = selectionItemsHashMap.get(itemName);

                    currentQuantity += 1;
                    // Update the hashmap with the new quantity
                    selectionItemsHashMap.put(itemName,currentQuantity);

                    //Update total amount
                    for (Object name: selectionItemsHashMap.keySet()) {
                        String key = (String) name;
                        if (key.equals(selectionItemArrayList.get(position).getSelectionName())) {
                            int eachPrice = Integer.parseInt(selectionItemArrayList.get(position).getSelectionPrice());
                            totalAmount += eachPrice;
                        }
                    }
                    // Display the new quantity
                    String stringCurrentQuantity = Integer.toString(currentQuantity);
                    tvDishQuantity.setText(stringCurrentQuantity);
                    //updateCartListener.onUpdateCart(totalAmount);
                }
            });
}
```

**EDIT**
A couple of points:
- When the cart is initially filled, I use this same code and it works fine.
- The problem occurs once the user returns to the cart and I have to repopulate it from a bundle. Everything works fine, except when the user goes straight to the cart and attempts to alter the quantity from there.

Comment: Where is the interface declared? I can't see any null in this code.

Comment: Post your adapter code pls

Comment: @The_Martian I updated the adapter code with the interface declaration.

Comment: @BachVu I posted almost all of the adapter since you requested. (Only left out a couple of clicklisteners for reducing and removing the items from the cart just to keep it concise).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass interface implementation into the constructor of Adapter as follows :

```
public SelectionAdapter(ArrayList<SelectionItem> selectionItemArrayList, HashMap<String, Integer> selectionItemsHashMap, int currentTotalAmount,UpdateCartListener updateCartListener ) {
    this.selectionItemArrayList = selectionItemArrayList;
    this.selectionItemsHashMap = selectionItemsHashMap;
    this.totalAmount = currentTotalAmount;
    this.updateCartListener = updateCartListener
}
```

This will provide an implementation of your interface on the initialization of your adapter so it will be not null when you are using it for update cart.

Comment: Thanks. How would I go about initializing this in the parent fragment before passing the interface?

Comment: I figured out the initialization part. Wasn't easy but you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forget assignment the updateCartListener in your adapter.

```
    SelectionAdapter(selectionItemArrayList, selectionItemsHashMap, totalAmount);

    cartItemsHashmap = selectionItemsHashMap;

    selectionAdapter.setUpdateCartListener(new SelectionAdapter.OnUpdateCartListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onUpdateCart(int updatedTotalAmount) {

                            String stringTotalAmount = Integer.toString(updatedTotalAmount);
                            Log.d(TAG, "received total:" +stringTotalAmount);
                            tvTotalAmount.setText("$"+ stringTotalAmount);
                            totalAmount = updatedTotalAmount;
                        }
                    });
     selectionRecycler.setAdapter(selectionAdapter);
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment.

Comment: @BVB09 As I said, The Solution Except Siddhpura Amit says, you also can do this like so.

Answer (score 0):

So you try to access the listener inside the `ViewHolder` which is probably the cause of the crash, what the standard way is setting the `OnClickListener` inside your adapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {        
    viewHolder.tvSelectItem.setText(selectionItemArrayList.get(position).getSelectionName());
    String quantity = Integer.toString(selectionItemArrayList.get(position).getSelectionQuantity());
    viewHolder.tvDishQuantity.setText(quantity);
    viewHolder.addQuantity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right; that is the standard way and was my initial approach but that had the same problem. Furthermore, the tvDishQuantity (the text view where I show the quantity for that item) could not be called to be updated despite it being declared public.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your updateCartListener begfore you use it. Do updateCartListener = new WhatverClassThatImplementsYourInterafce() before you use it or make your method to override Default if you are using Java 8 using [the new FunctionalInterface in java.util.Function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/default-methods-java/).

Comment: So I tried the approach you said i.e. SelectionAdapter.OnUpdateCartListener = new MenuFragment(); before invoking the listener and I am still getting the same problem. Yes, I am using Java 8 so I tried that alternate suggestion as well. Altered to "public class MenuFragment extends Fragment implements SelectionAdapter.OnUpdateCartListener and implemented the method by doing the same thing I am doing right now inside the method. But in vain. I get the same error.

Comment: Did you put breakpoint and debug to see if the listener is actually null because that is what the exception is telling you. Is the fragment available at the time you are calling the method? I can't see all your code so I can only guess. But it looks like there is something null.

Comment: Yes, I started doing it after Siddpura mentioned it. I took his advice and now it's working. Thanks for your help nonetheless. I modified my code so that it follows the Java 8 implementation suggestion and now it looks cleaner.